# Google Spreadsheet. Retrieve only one cell from ImportData-result

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I have this function:

```
=ImportData("http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&a=0&b=7&c=2013&d=0&e=7&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv")
```

...which returns how a given stock was doing on a given date. The function returns a csv that looks like this:

```
Date      Open  High    Low    Close    Volume    Adj Close
1/7/2013  522   529.3   515.2  523.9    17291300  514.05
```

I.E: 2 rows and 7 columns is pasted in the cell I have the function in.

I am only interested in the value written in the Close-column. So is there a way to filter out this value so that "523.9" is all I would receive from the function written above?

Would be great if this is possible without storing the full table somewhere else first, but  any solution is better than no solution of course. This is for Google Spreadsheet but perhaps its the same solution as in Excel.

Comment: Updated with an answer.

Comment: See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/44719/29140 for exclusive Google Spreadsheet formulas. The other tags are of no use (since they do not work) and therefore you should've asked this on [webapps.se] !!

Answer (score -1):

Received an answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339447/google-spreadsheet-retrieve-only-one-cell-from-importdata-result

The answer was:

```
=INDEX(ImportData("http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&a=0&b=7&c=2013&d=0&e=7&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv"),2,5)
```

Comment: While it's nice that you're following up on this question to resolve it, please note that we consider cross-posting on multiple SE sites to be abusive behavior. [More about our policy here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2807/shouldnt-cross-posting-be-allowed).